# Map a list of objects manually using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am using automapper to map one complex object to another where the source object has a list of objects whose properties do not match the list of objects in the destination.

So, i am manually going through the list in the source using Linq and mapping it to the destination object.

The issue is, the destination object is a database object:

Source Object:

```
public class AutomationDetailsResponse
    {        
        public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }    
        
        public int EngagementId { get; set; } 
        
        public string ServiceRequestName { get; set; }      
        
        public Guid ServiceRequestGUID { get; set; }    
        
        public string OfficeId { get; set; }
        
        public string CountryId { get; set; }  
        
        public string EngagementCode { get; set; }  
        
        public string CanvasDocumentUri { get; set; }  
        
        public string CanvasAudienceUri { get; set; }     

        public List<RequestFile> InputRequestFiles { get; set; }  
        
        public List<RequestFile> OutputRequestFiles { get; set; }  
        
        public string Status { get; set; }       

        public string RequestInitiatedByName { get; set; }    
        
        public string RequestInitiatedBy { get; set; }   
        
        public int DataCenterId { get; set; }   
        
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }  
        
        public DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }       

        public List<ActivityFeed> ActivityFeeds { get; set; }   
        
        public List<Guid> TaskIds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public int CanvasRequestId { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestFile
    {       
        public Guid Id { get; set; }       
        public int FileSequence { get; set; }       
        public Guid GroupId { get; set; }       
        public string GroupName { get; set; }       
        public string FileType { get; set; }       
        public string FileName { get; set; }       
        public int FileSize { get; set; }        
        public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityFeed
    {       
        public int CreatedById { get; set; }       
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }      
        public string Description { get; set; }       
        public int ActivityType { get; set; }       
        public string UserName { get; set; }        
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Destination Object:

```
[Table(nameof(AutomationRequest), Schema = Schemas.SAH)]
    public class AutomationRequest : EntityBase, ICreatedDate, IModifiedDate
    {
        [Required]
        public int CanvasEnvironmentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid AppInstanceId { get; set; }

        public Guid CanvasRequestGUID { get; set; }

        public int CanvasRequestId { get; set; }      
        
        public int DownstreamStatusId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CanvasStatusId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid ServiceCatalogId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string RequestName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string EngagementId { get; set; }        

        [Required]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int DataCenterId { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeletedFromSAH { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeletedFromCAH { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string CreatedByEmail { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string CreatedByName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(38)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string OriginatedFrom { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public string NavigationUrl { get; set; }

        public int? Version { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CanvasEnvironmentId))]
        public virtual Environment CanvasEnvironment { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CountryId))]
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ServiceCatalogId))]
        public virtual ServiceCatalog ServiceCatalog { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CanvasStatusId))]
        public virtual AutomationRequestStatus CanvasStatus { get; set; }        

        public virtual ICollection<AutomationRequestInputFile> InputFiles { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AutomationRequestOutputFile> OutputFiles { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AutomationRequestTask> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
```

```
[Table(nameof(AutomationRequestInputFile), Schema = Schemas.SAH)]
    public class AutomationRequestInputFile : EntityBase, ICreatedDate, IModifiedDate
    { 
        [Required]
        public Guid CanvasGroupId { get; set; }
        
        public Guid CanvasDocumentId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(38)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(38)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]        
        public Guid AutomationRequestId { get; set; }      
        
        public string FileType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(AutomationRequestId))]
        public virtual AutomationRequest AutomationRequest { get; set; }

       
    }
```

```
 public class EntityBase
    {
        public EntityBase()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the mapping configuration:

```
CreateMap<AutomationDetailsResponse, AutomationRequest>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.CanvasRequestGUID,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ServiceRequestGUID))
                .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.RequestName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ServiceRequestName))
                .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.InputFiles,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InputRequestFiles.Select(x => new AutomationRequestInputFile { CanvasGroupId = x.GroupId, CanvasDocumentId = x.DocumentId, FileName = x.FileName, FileType = x.FileType })))
                .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.OutputFiles,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OutputRequestFiles.Select(x => new AutomationRequestOutputFile { CanvasDocumentId = x.DocumentId,FileName = x.FileName, FileType = x.FileType, FileSize = x.FileSize, CreatedDate = x.CreatedAt })))
                .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.CreatedByName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RequestInitiatedByName))
                 .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.CreatedDate,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedAt))
                 .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.ModifiedDate,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastUpdatedAt))
                 .ForMember(
                    dst => dst.Tasks,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TaskIds.Select(x => new AutomationRequestTask { CanvasId = x })))
                ;
```

The mapping works. The issue is this:

```
var automation = await _dbContext.AutomationRequests.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.CanvasRequestGUID == automationDetails.ServiceRequestGUID);
 _mapper.Map(automationDetails, automation);
 _dbContext.Update(automation);
 await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The update fails because, in the mapping configuration, we are create a new instance AutomationRequestInputFile which triggers the constructor in EntityBase, creating a new Id. When EF Core tries to update the row, it does not find the record because the Id has changed.

I have been trying to solve this for 1 day now and havent made any progress.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: would you please share the error message please?

Comment: database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). This is the error because the automapper changes the Id of the AutomationRequestInputFile and when i try to update, the update fails because EF Core can't find the record in db because the id is wrong.

Comment: What is the business requirement that you need to solve with this code? It's sound counter intuitive that you pull a record from a database, then map it to another object and update that record. 90% of the times you pull out a record from the database, make some changes on it and sent it right back to the database. Why would you map it to another object.

Comment: There is a business requirement to do this.

Comment: have you tried ```_dbContext.AutomationRequests.Update(automation)``` instead of```_dbContext.Update(automation);```

Comment: Yeah tried that too. The issue is not with the update. The issue is with the mapper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223894/discussion-between-rodrigo-ramirez-and-sriram-arunachalam).

Answer (score 2):

You're not using AutoMapper correctly since you're still manually constructing the `AutomationRequestInputFile` objects (by using LINQ .Select()).

The solution is to add a second mapping for `RequestFile` to `AutomationRequestInputFile` and remove the Select in the MapFrom config of the ´InputFiles´ property.

Here's a working .NET Fiddle (properties & types not provided in your question have been omitted): https://dotnetfiddle.net/9qizfk

Comment: I thought this would solve it. I did exactly what you suggested but still a new id is being created for each inputrequestfile after the mapping and the db update still fails. I even added:
`.ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()) ` for this map: CreateMap<RequestFile, AutomationRequestInputFile>()